# Dealing with negative values in a positive regression

Tags: regression, multiple-regression, linear

What is the best way to deal with two sets of independent variables that have two different value ranges?

I have one data set with values ranging from -1 to 1 and another data set ranging from 0 to 1.

Example Data Set 1:

```
.53    .01   .22  .907  .37 .41  0.1  .22
```

Example Data Set Two

```
-0.1  -0.27  .55  .504  .504  1.0   0.0  -.42
```

I'm assuming the best way to deal with this is to convert my -1 to 1 data set into  a 0 to 1 data set but am not sure if there might be an existing formula or way to do so that doesn't require conversion. Perhaps multiple regression should be used instead?

Comment: I standardized my data using in the -1 to 1 data set using (x+1)/2

Answer (score 1):

What you are thinking about is called *standardizing* the data so that all regressors live in a more or less common range. Usually, this is done by subtracting every entry of each column by the column's mean (so the resulting column has mean 0) and dividing by its standard deviation (so it will have deviation 1). However, this isn't always necessary. In my experience, a good rule of thumb is to standardize whenever the data columns are measured in different units (or are measures of different phenomena). In this case, standardizing makes the columns and the magnitude of their resulting coefficients comparable to each other.